# Java/Java EE : to invoke getter method from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to invoke a getter method (returns String value) of a Java class from JSP by using "jsp:usebean", but it returns a null value. What I don't understand is why it can't return the updated value.

1. Can someone shed some light on this?
2. Should I use a `Cookie` to get the value from JSP?

Comment: can you show your code, please ?

Comment: Definitely don't use a cookie to get the value.  You probably just need to turn up your logging level to DEBUG so that you can more clearly see what's going on with your bean.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post some code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're using (Struts, plain Servlets, etc.) but essentially you need to add an attribute to the [ServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) like:

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    // other fields, getters, setters
}

public void method(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setFirstName("Obama");
    httpServletRequest.setAttribute("person", p);
}
```

and in your JSP:

```
<jsp:getProperty object="person" property="firstName" />
```

or if you use [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/reference/docs/index.html):

```
<c:out value="${person.firstName}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is simple.

In java file:

```
package loga;
class bean{

String name;
public void setName(String Uname)
{
this.name=Uname;
}
public void getName()
{
return name;
}
```

In jsp file, call this method as:

```
<jsp:useBean id="object" class="loga.bean">
<jsp:setproperty name="object" property="Name" Value="XXXX"/>
<jsp:getProperty name="object" property="Name"/>
</jsp:usebean>
```

Here, the property indicates the method name of the getName() in the java class.
To pass value from other controls use param property and give name of the control.